# Работа с данными из БД

Tags: java, postgresql

У меня создана база данных с полями `name_of_organization` и `money_of_organization`. Мне нужно, чтобы введенные в текстовое поле названия организаций находились в базе данных (такое я реализовал), и при введении в другое текстовое поле суммы у одной организации (введенной) эта сумма вычиталась, а у другой увеличивалась. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как это реализовать

Класс Controller

```
    public void check2(String loginProve){

        DatabaseHandler read = new DatabaseHandler();
        User pr = new User();
        pr.setOrganization(loginProve);
        ResultSet first = read.getInformation(pr);

        int fg =  0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (!first.next()) break;
            } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                throwables.printStackTrace();
            }
            fg++;
        }

        if(fg >=1)
            System.out.println("Организация 2 найдена");
        else
            System.out.println("Такой организации нет!");
    }

    public void check(String loginProve){
        DatabaseHandler read = new DatabaseHandler();
        User pr = new User();
        pr.setOrganization(loginProve);
        ResultSet first = read.getInformation(pr);

        int fg =  0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (!first.next()) break;
            } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                throwables.printStackTrace();
            }
            fg++;
        }
        if(fg >=1)
        System.out.println("Организация 1 найдена");
        else
            System.out.println("Такой организации нет!");
    }
```

Класс для подключения к БД с методами чтения из БД и записи в БД

Класс User

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не надо так делать. Случайное двукратное нажатие - и затрахаешься восстанавливать.

Comment: Добавьте таблицу операций, и в неё записывайте перемещение средств. А текущий баланс считайте динамически на основании исходного баланса и выполненных операций.

Comment: пожалуйста, дайте вопросу осмысленный заголовок, кратко описывающий суть вопроса ([edit])

Comment: Спасибо я уже все порешал, создал два метода оба перезаписывают найденную строку из БД, но один метод прибавляет, а другой вычитает.